# Error with launching script in MATLAB for ROS

Tags: ros, ros-noetic, universal-robot

I keep getting this error everytime that the last line does not execute and takes me to the file `function generateAndTransferLaunchScriptGettingStarted` which points to   `putFile(device,fullfile(tempdir,'launchUR.sh'),'~/')`

```
ur5e = loadrobot('universalUR5e');

deviceAddress = '172.28.9.67';
ROSFolder = '/opt/ros/noetic';
WorkSpaceFolder = '~/ur_ws';
robotAddress = '127.0.0.1';

device = rosdevice('localhost');
device.ROSFolder = ROSFolder
interface = 'Gazebo';

generateAndTransferLaunchScriptGettingStarted(device,WorkSpaceFolder,interface,robotAddress);
```

Below is the function for `generateAndTransferLaunchScriptGettingStarted`

```
function generateAndTransferLaunchScriptGettingStarted(device,WorkSpaceFolder,interface,RobotAddress)
    
    % Open a file to write set of commands to lauunch interface with
    % simulated UR5 in gazebo or URSim
    fid=fopen(fullfile(tempdir,"launchUR.sh"),"w+");
    fprintf(fid,"#!/bin/sh\n");
    fprintf(fid,"export SVGA_VGPU10=0\n");
    fprintf(fid,"export ROS_IP=%s\n",device.DeviceAddress);
    fprintf(fid,"export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://$ROS_IP:11311\n");

    if isequal(interface,'Gazebo')
        fprintf(fid,"gnome-terminal --title=\42Simulated UR5 Robot\42 -- /bin/bash -c 'source %s/setup.bash; source %s/devel/setup.bash; roslaunch ur_gazebo ur5e_bringup.launch'",device.ROSFolder,WorkSpaceFolder);
    elseif isequal(interface,'URSim')
        fprintf(fid,"gnome-terminal --title=\42Simulated UR5 Robot\42 -- /bin/bash -c 'source %s/setup.bash; source %s/devel/setup.bash; roslaunch ur_robot_driver ur5e_bringup.launch robot_ip:=127.0.0.1'",device.ROSFolder,WorkSpaceFolder);
    elseif isequal(interface,'Hardware')
        fprintf(fid,"gnome-terminal --title=\42UR5e Robot Driver\42 -- /bin/bash -c 'source %s/setup.bash; source %s/devel/setup.bash; roslaunch ur_robot_driver ur5e_bringup.launch robot_ip:=%s'",device.ROSFolder,WorkSpaceFolder,RobotAddress);
    end
    
    fclose(fid);

    % Copy file into ROS device
    putFile(device,fullfile(tempdir,'launchUR.sh'),'~/')

    % Make the shell script executable
    system(device,'chmod a+x ~/launchUR.sh');
end
```

Following is the error that I am getting:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Error in ros.codertarget.internal.LocalSystemExecutor/putFile (line 19)
            copyfile(localFile,remoteFile);

Error in rosdevice/putFile (line 84)
            putFile(obj.SystemExecutor,varargin{:})

Error in generateAndTransferLaunchScriptGettingStarted (line 22)
    putFile(device,fullfile(tempdir,'launchUR.sh'),'~/')
Can someone point out the error?
```

This link contains what I am trying to do.[https://de.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/robotmanipulator/ug/getting-started-simulated-ur.html#responsive_offcanvas]

Comment: "I keep getting this error": which error? What behavior are you seeing vs. what do you expect to see?

Comment: Hey @cst0 I have updated my question by adding the error.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, the reason that

```
generateAndTransferLaunchScriptGettingStarted
```

is unable to start is because

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

You need to verify that the filename, and directory, and volume label are all valid for your particular operating system and computer setup.